# Asp.net MVC changing the progress bar value with every button click

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, progress-bar

I am trying to make a progress bar change with button clicks. If i click just one button progress bar value should be %10 (i am calculating the value manually. it can change like %20 or %30 vs) but if i click 2 buttons the value should be divided by 2, if i click 3 buttons value should be divided by 3 etc. here is my code

```
@foreach (var u in Model.calisan)
                    {
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <div class="profile-sidebar">
                                <div class="portlet light profile-sidebar-portlet">
                                    <div class="profile-userpic" id="personelF-@u.PersonelID">
                                        <img src="~/Araclar/Resim/noimage.png" class="img-responsive" alt="" style="width:150px;height:150px; margin-left:10px; border:none;" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="profile-usertitle">
                                        <div id="moda1" class="profile-usertitle-name" style="margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center;" data-ad="@u.AdiSoyadi"> <b>@u.AdiSoyadi</b></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="profile-userbuttons" style="margin-bottom:-30px;text-align:center;">

                                        <button type="button"  class="btn btn-circle green btn-sm undo" onclick="dolulukHesapla('personel-@u.PersonelID','@u.AdiSoyadi', '@u.PersonelID')">SEÇ</button>
                                        <input type="text" hidden="hidden" id="kullaniciAd" />
                                        <input type="text" hidden="hidden" id="kullaniciID" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <hr />
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <div class="profile-stat-title"> Şu An </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                        <div class="progress">
                                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="@u.suAnkiDoluluk" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: @u.suAnkiDoluluk%">
                                            </div>
                                            <span class="progress-completed">@u.suAnkiDoluluk%</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <div class="profile-stat-title"> Olacak </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                        <div class="progress" id="personel-@u.PersonelID">
                                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="@u.suAnkiDoluluk" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: @u.sonrakiDoluluk%">
                                            </div>
                                            <span class="progress-completed">@u.sonrakiDoluluk%</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                    }




function dolulukHesapla(Id, ad, personalID) {
    var values = {

        personalID: personalID
    }
    var adet = document.getElementById('adet').value;
    if (adet == 0) {
        console.log("Adet 0 kısmı");
        alert("Adet 0 olarak İş Emri Atanamaz.");
        return;
    }
    else {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'Post',
            url: '/Siparis/DolulukHesapla',
            data: JSON.stringify(values),
            dataType: 'JSON',
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            success: function (gelenDeg) {
                var calismaSuresi = parseInt(gelenDeg);
                console.log(calismaSuresi);
                $("#personellerRow").find(".img-responsive").each(function () {
                    $(this).css("border", "5px outset red;");
                    console.log($(this).attr('style'));
                });

                var nowValue = $("#" + Id).find(".progress-bar").attr("aria-valuenow");
                var toplamSure = document.getElementById('pTSure').value;
                var toplamSureOran = ((toplamSure / calismaSuresi) * 100);


                var Toplam = parseInt(nowValue) + parseInt(toplamSureOran);

                $("#" + Id).find(".progress-bar").attr("aria-valuenow", Toplam);
                $("#" + Id).find(".progress-bar").css("width", Toplam + "%");

                $("#" + Id).find(".progress-completed").text(Toplam + "%");

                //    //$("#" + Id).find(".img-responsive").css("border", "5px outset red;");

                $("#kullaniciAd").val(ad);
                $("#kullaniciID").val(personalID);

            },
            error: function () {
                toastr["error"]('İşlem sırasında hata oluştu');
            }
        });
    }
    
}
```

thanks for help in advance. I hope i made my point clear.

Comment: what issue are you having with the code now, exactly? What does it actually do, compared to what you expected / wanted? Please explain the specific problem as well as just the overall requirement.

Comment: this code is the code that i am using right now. I can click a button and give progress bar %10 value. But if i click another button, it gives another %10 value but i want to click multiple buttons and each time i click a button value should be divided by it. For example if i click 1 button bar should be %60. But if i click 3 different buttons each progress bar should be %20. i hope i made it more clear for you.

Comment: So, you are saying it's possible there might 1, or 2, or 3, or possible more buttons on the page which call the `dolulukHesapla()` function? And you don't know beforehand how many buttons will be there? Or, are you talking about clicking the same button multiple times? Also are you saying there could be more than one progress bar? Should there be the same number as there are buttons? What are the rules? Your example code only contains one button, but two progress bars, so I'm not sure if I have understood correctly or fully.

Comment: It _sounds like_ your code needs to detect how many buttons, and how many progress bars, exist are on the page, and then do some maths based on that. But it's hard to be certain, because your description is not totally precise or detailed.

Comment: Maybe you can define a global variable to store the count of clicked buttons and calculate the progress bar value.

Comment: sorry english is not my first language so i will try my best explaining. There are 19 employees in the page and each employee has it's own progress bar and button. So i assign work to this employees. So there are 19 buttons.https://i.hizliresim.com/fAcUTC.png here is the page is looking like. first progress bar is representing the now value, second one is after the button click.